# What is the structure of a table that stores multilingual data in Yii2?

Tags: phpmyadmin, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new in yii2 and I need help to building my database ..
 for example In the control panel  I need form (pruducts) to insert the same data but two different languages , for example I have (field_title_en ,field_title_ar)etc..
Will I create one table with all these fields or divide the table into two separate tables ?
(Note that the tables in the project are many)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [this module](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-translate-manager). You create you database tables with only 1 field per language (just `title', for example). With that module, you have the possibility to specify which field(s) of which table(s) should be translated. Then, you activate the language(s) you want to translate your application to, and the values of the fields of the tables you specified will appear there for you to translate.

Comment: Thanks for your interaction with my problem..I followed this module but I found it complicated and I can't understand it well .. Can I find any  easier idea ? I'm sory I'm very beginner in web programming .